# Undefined React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a value.

It goes from Africa -> FetchContext -> Jumbotron.
When it reaches Jumbotron it's undefined.

I think it's because Africa is never called again.

I send the value of the continent to a context.
The idea is that this is a travel review site. All continents are ordered in a navbar.
The Africa-component gets called whenever "Africa" in the navbar is clicked.

```
const Africa = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <DataProvider continent={["Africa"]} />
```

This is the context:

```
const DataContext = React.createContext();
export default DataContext;

export class DataProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log("Props " + this.props.continent + " in fetchcontext.js");

    this.state = {
      title: '',
    };
  }

  updateState() {
    this.setState({
      title: this.props.continent,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Comp did mount: " + this.props.continent)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Comp did unmount: " + this.props.continent)

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider value={{ value: this.props.continent }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Wherever I console log this.props.continent, it's always the correct corresponding continent.
However, as soon as I target a review, my jumbotron spawns, and here, the value is undefined.

This is my jumbotron:

```
const JumbotronPage = () => {
  return (
    <section className="page-section">
      <DataProvider>
        <DataContext.Consumer>
          {(value) => (
            <MDBContainer>
                          {console.log(value)}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid but I cannot figure it out.
Thanks

TLDR;
I pass prop to middle-component, setting the prop as state, sending the state as context to jumbotron-component. Here, the context is undefined.

Edit:
SOLVED. I had to understand how to pass it to it's children.

Comment: Why are you wrapping a new `DataProvider` in for your `DataContext.Consumer` ? I assume that you already wrapped it on the outer level of the `JumbotronPage` component aren't you.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I followed some tutorial. I'm quite new to this. What do you mean by "wrapped it on the outer level"?

Comment: DataProvider or Africa component must wrap your entire App. You need no use DataProvider for each component

Comment: @Jannemannen I think the issue was because that you have wrapped multiple times using `DataProvider`. You should wrap your whole App once using your `DataProvider` then you can access the context value  in the `DataProvier`'s children

Comment: I hear you, however, I need to be able to use each and every continent. Every continent-component is built up like Africa.

Comment: In such a case you need not render DataProvider as a child of Africa but use some function from dataProvider to set the state. DataProvider need not have muliple instances otherwise the closest instance to the component using it will be used

Comment: Alright. Thanks for all input. I'll try to gather it, understand and apply it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys. Helped me figure it out. Cheers for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JumbotronPage` has to be a child of `DataProvider`.

In your case, `this.props.children` is not used within `DataProvider`.

```
const DataContext = React.createContext();

const JumbotronPage = () => {
  // ["Africa"]
  return (
    <DataContext.Consumer>
      {value => {
        console.log(value);
      }}
    </DataContext.Consumer>
  );
};

class DataProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DataContext.Provider value={this.props.continent}>
        {this.props.children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <DataProvider continent={['Africa']}>
      <JumbotronPage />
    </DataProvider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-wright-c1lzk]

Comment: I hear you! 
I do want to be able to pass each and every continent to the jumbotron. Am I dumb for thinking that this will only hardcode "Africa"?

Comment: As for now its hardcoded... You can put any variable instead of `['Africa']`

Comment: I don't quite understand "wrapping app". Jumbotron, app, fetchcontext and the continent are all in different files. My App consists of routes to different paths of the site.

Comment: What is the question? It all explained in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context